# Repeat rows in a table based on a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. The first Table TBL1 has only one column, which includes date:

```
[date]
2017-10-03                 
2017-10-04
2017-10-05
2017-10-06
....
```

The second table TBL2:

```
Date            Code           Index        Domain
2017-10-03       1               542         xxx.com
2017-10-03       680             652         xxx.com
2017-10-06       1               235         xxx.com
2017-10-06       680             125         xxx.com
```

I would like to have such a structure:

```
Date            Code           Index        Domain
2017-10-03       1               542         xxx.com
2017-10-03       680             652         xxx.com
2017-10-04       1               NULL        xxx.com
2017-10-04       680             NULL        xxx.com
2017-10-05       1               NULL        xxx.com
2017-10-05       680             NULL        xxx.com
2017-10-06       1               235         xxx.com
2017-10-06       680             125         xxx.com
```

How can I generate something like this in SQL?

Comment: It is unclear where `domain` comes from.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and a `left join` to bring in the columns:

```
select t1.date, cd.code, t2.index, cd.domain
from tbl1 t1 cross join
     (select distinct code, domain from tbl2) cd left join
     tbl2 t2
     on t2.date = t1.date and t2.code = cd.code and t2.domain = cd.domain;
```